# Why does my integer array display random values?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to make a program that stores information about employees however when I try to store there salary the output is a random integer.

The code worked perfectly before I turned the the original `Salary` (**Not a array**) to`Salary[i]`, which I did to be able to calculate the the Total Salary (`totSlry`)

```
int NumofEmpo;
printf("How much Employees do you want to add?\n");
scanf(" %d", &NumofEmpo); 

char Name[25], Service[20];                //All the variables that the user
int DOB, Salary[NumofEmpo], totSlry = 0;   //info will get stored in

    for(int i = 0; i != NumofEmpo; i++)
    {
        fgetc(stdin);

        printf("Name: ");
        fgets(Name, 25, stdin);
        printf("Service: ");
        fgets(Service, 20, stdin);
        printf("Date of Birth: ");
        scanf("%d", &DOB);
        printf("Salary: ");
        scanf("%d", &Salary[i]);
        printf("\n");
        totSlry = totSlry + Salary[i];

        FILE * fpointer = fopen("Employees.txt", "a");

        fprintf(fpointer, "Name: %s", Name);
        fprintf(fpointer, "Service: %s", Service);
        fprintf(fpointer, "Date of Birth: %d\n", DOB);
        fprintf(fpointer, "Salary: %d\n\n", Salary);

        fclose(fpointer);
    }
    FILE * fpointer0 = fopen("Employees.txt", "a");
    fprintf(fpointer0, "Total Salary: %d", totSlry);
    fclose(fpointer0);
```

I expected the the output to show me the salary of all the employees in the file like the following:

```
Name: Ahmed
Service: Security
Date of Birth: 1995
Salary: 100

Name: John
Service: Accountant
Date of Birth: 2000
Salary: 200

Total Salary: 300
```

But the actual output would come out like this:

```
Name: Ahmed
Service: Security
Date of Birth: 1995
Salary: -24087712

Name: John
Service: Accountant
Date of Birth: 2000
Salary: -24087712

Total Salary: 300
```

Comment: `fprintf(fpointer, "Salary: %d\n\n", Salary);` prints the array **address** to the file. (and invokes *Undefined Behavior* due to the mismatch in conversion specifier and type) Also, don't *skimp* on buffer size. Consider reading into a temporary buffer of at least `1K` (`1024 bytes`) and then copy to `name` and `service` (this will ensure a complete line is consumed if the input exceeds the size of either and give you an opportunity to handle the error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has

```
fprintf(fpointer, "Salary: %d\n\n", Salary);
```

According to your program logic, it should be

```
fprintf(fpointer, "Salary: %d\n\n", Salary[i]);
```

You were trying to print the base address of the Salary int array as an actual integer, hence the random numbers.